# Merging streams that are stored in array

Tags: java, arrays, merge, java-stream

I have an array of streams. These streams include integers. I want to merge these streams using only one statement.
Here is an example:

```
Stream<?>[] arr = new Stream<?>[3];
arr[0] = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
arr[1] = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
arr[2] = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

Stream<?> mergedStream = Stream.concat(Stream.concat(arr[0], arr[1]), arr[2]);
```

The last line throws the following error:
"finished with non-zero exit value 1"  but I hope my intention is clear. However, I usually don't know the amount of streams that have to be merged.
I was thinking about the following solution but it doesn't work:

```
Stream<?> mergedStream =Arrays.stream(arr).flatMap(Function.identity());
```

Comment: I tried that with a `List<Stream<String>>` and it works, in both Java 11 and Java 17. I also tried it with a `Stream<?>[]` and that too works. What doesn't it do that you want it to do?

Comment: I'm not that experienced to be honest, but I just tried to print out all elements of the mergedStream using `mergedStream.forEach(System.out::println);` and it would always return the error "finished with non-zero exit value 1".

Comment: I used jshell to execute the same code (declare and initialize `arr`, use `flatMap`, use `forEach`) and it works just fine. What command are you executing to get this error?

Comment: It's only this command that causes the error: `mergedStream.forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Where did you use `forEach`? Can you give me an example of your code?

Comment: @crofton I copy-pasted all code from you into jshell: the first block minus the `mergedStream`; the updated `mergedStream`; and the `forEach` from your comment. I agree that we need a reproducable example, including exactly at what stage it goes wrong (compile, run).

Comment: Whatever is causing your error “finished with non-zero exit value 1”, it is not the code you’ve posted. Further, it’s not clear what problem “but it doesn't work” is supposed to describe. For the posted code, it works as good or bad as the first variant. Both work with a subsequent `mergedStream.forEach(System.out::println);` But the real solution is not to have an array of streams in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try `Stream<Integer>[] arr = new Stream<Integer>[3];`

Comment: java doesn't allow that since you are trying to create a generic array